# Mirroring an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

I am trying to mirror an Array. In other words, if I create an array that looks like this (The user gives the size):

```
0 2 4 6 7
8 9 10 11 12
```

After mirroring, it should look like this:

```
 0 2 4 2 0
 8 9 10 9 8
```

However, it doesn't work when I make it a 3 x 5 array or bigger. It repeats the same number like this:

```
0 2 4 2 2
8 9 10 8 8
```

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Mirror {
public static void main (String [] args)
{

    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter number of rows: ");
    int rows = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter number of columns:");
    int columns = kb.nextInt();

    int [][] mirror = new int [rows][columns];

    int sum =0;

    for (int r = 0; r<mirror.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<mirror[r].length ; c++)
        {
            mirror[r][c]= sum;

            sum= sum+2;
        }
    }

    for (int r = 0; r<mirror.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<mirror[r].length ; c++)
        {
        System.out.print (mirror[r][c]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    int add = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r<mirror.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = mirror[r].length/2 +1; c<mirror[r].length ; c++)
        {
            for (int x= 0; x<mirror[r].length/2; x=x++)
            {
                mirror[r][c] = mirror [r][x];

            }

        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int r = 0; r<mirror.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<mirror[r].length ; c++)
        {
        System.out.print (mirror[r][c]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}

  }
```

Do you guys have any ideas on where my problem is? I tried to debug but I can't find the problem. Sorry and thankyou, I am a beginner.

Comment: Perhaps your approach isn't right. You should be trying to split your array in half, excluding the middle value (if any), reversing the contents of the first half and then writing the changes to the new array.

Comment: That's a good idea! thank you. I am to give to try that approach @KenoClayton

Comment: Let me know how that attempt goes

Answer (score 0):

You are doing more loops than the necessary.

Try changing this:

```
for (int r = 0; r<mirror.length; r++)
{
    /*for (int c = mirror[r].length/2 +1; c<mirror[r].length ; c++)
    {
        for (int x= 0; x<mirror[r].length/2; x=x++)
        {
            mirror[r][c] = mirror [r][mirror[r].length/2 +1 -c];

        }

    }*/

    for(int c=0; c<mirror[r].length; c++){
        if(c<mirror[r].length/2.0)
            mirror[r][mirror[r].length-1-c] = mirror[r][c];
    }
}
```

You only need one loop for row, in this loop using an if (to detect the middle), you can do what you want.